# Ledger nano not detected by monero GUI

Tags: command-line

Ubuntu detects the device Ledger Nano X on the terminal with the command `lsusb`. When I go to create a monero GUI wallet, it says:

```
failed to generate new wallet: Wrong device Status: 0x6e00 (SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED), EXPECTED 0x9000 (SW_OK), MASK 0xffff"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include i) the output of the `lsusb` command you mention and ii) the command you use to generate the wallet.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently there is a miner included in the Monero GUI software whereby AV software steps in. See this exchange with proposed solution: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10798/my-antivirus-av-software-blocks-quarantines-the-monero-gui-wallet-is-there

Comment: Unless OP has installed antivirus on their Ubuntu system, there's no AV by default to kill the program or its components.